# Removing an item from a list in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, android-sqlite, xamarin.forms.listview

The issue i'm having is when I delete a row from my list in Xamarin forms, I have it set up so when the user wants to delete something, they will get a pop up asking if they really want to delete. If they push yes it removes the item from the list..(not a problem) but if the user says no it still removes the item (temperately) you then refresh the page and it will come back. I am wondering what I have wrong in my code. so it doesn't remove the item unless you push yes..

```
async void OnDeleteBook(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var book = (sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as BooksIWant;

    if (await DisplayAlert("Warning", $"Are you sure you want to delete {book.Author} {book.BookTitle}?", "Yes", "No"))
        await _connection.DeleteAsync(book);
    _booksIWant.Remove(book);
}
```

Comment: Note that using `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` can automatically refresh the items in the page when there is a change, so you don't need to manually remove from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `{}` to create a block of statements.  Without them, only the statement immediately after the `IF` is executed;

```
if (await DisplayAlert("Warning", $"Are you sure you want to delete {book.Author} {book.BookTitle}?", "Yes", "No"))
{
  await _connection.DeleteAsync(book);
  _booksIWant.Remove(book);
}
```

This is basic C#, not anything specific to Xamarin.

Comment: Thank you. It always the little things that you forget. I feel like an a** because I know this ( Well I guess I don't know it well enough..LOL) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should code like below

```
async void OnDeleteBook(object sender, EventArgs e){
var book = (sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as BooksIWant;

if (await DisplayAlert("Warning", $"Are you sure you want to delete {book.Author} {book.BookTitle}?", "Yes", "No")){
    await _connection.DeleteAsync(book);
_booksIWant.Remove(book);}}
```

Delete and Remove method call needs to be inside the if loop